# Memory leak of java.util.ref.Finalizer while Finalizer thread is waiting

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm, finalize

Analysing a heap dump I look for instances of java.lang.ref.Finalizer class. java.lang.ref.Finalizer has 'next' and 'prev' member fields for maintaining linked list. I always get FileInputStream as a tail of the list and FileOutputStream as previous entry to it (analysed several heap dumps). File descriptors for FileInputStream and FileOutputStream are always 0 and 1 respectively:

```
+---[Pending Finalization] java.lang.ref.Finalizer           
| |                                                          
| +---queue  java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue [Stack Local]      
| |                                                          
| +---referent  java.io.FileInputStream                     
| | |                                                        
| | +---closed = boolean false                               
| | |                                                        
| | +---closeLock  java.lang.Object                          
| | |                                                        
| | +---fd  java.io.FileDescriptor                           
| |   |                                                      
| |   +---closed = boolean false                             
| |   |                                                      
| |   +---fd = int 0                                         
| |   |                                                       
| |   +---parent  java.io.FileInputStream                    
| |                                                          
| +---prev  [Pending Finalization] java.lang.ref.Finalizer   
|   |                                                        
|   +---queue  java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue [Stack Local]    
|   |                                                        
|   +---next  [Pending Finalization] java.lang.ref.Finalizer 
|   |                                                        
|   +---referent  java.io.FileOutputStream                   
|   | |                                                      
|   | +---append = boolean false                             
|   | |                                                      
|   | +---closed = boolean false                             
|   | |                                                       
|   | +---closeLock  java.lang.Object                        
|   | |                                                     
|   | +---fd  java.io.FileDescriptor                         
|   |   |                                                    
|   |   +---closed = boolean false                           
|   |   |                                                    
|   |   +---fd = int 1  0x00000001                           
|   |   |                                                    
|   |   +---parent  java.io.FileOutputStream                 
|   |                                                         
|   +---prev  [Pending Finalization] java.lang.ref.Finalizer
```

1. Why always FileInputStream and FileOutputStream are at the tail of the ReferenceQueue?
2. Aren't they collected by garbage collector because I observe only Allocation Failure GC not Full GC occuring?
3. Why descriptors are always 0 and 1 for them?

Comment: You are leaking file input and output streams. Solution: don't.

Comment: @user207421, unfortunately, your reply does not look like an answer to neither of the 3 questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the following test program will shed some light on it:

```
Field fd = FileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredField("fd");
fd.setAccessible(true);
System.out.println("stdin:  "+fd.get(FileDescriptor.in));
System.out.println("stdout: "+fd.get(FileDescriptor.out));
System.out.println("stderr: "+fd.get(FileDescriptor.err));
```

```
stdin:  0
stdout: 1
stderr: 2
```

<sup>[Ideone](https://ideone.com/xW5jrO), Note that for JDK 8, this applies to Unix like systems only</sup>

In other words, you are looking at the file streams encapsulated by `System.in` and `System.out` and, of course, these will never get garbage-collected and usually, you also don’t call `close()` on them.

The finalization does not support any kind of opt-out, so any instance of a class with a “non trivial `finalize()` method” will get a finalizer reference upon construction, even when the creator knows that the object will never get finalized.

The most recent JDK versions use a [`Cleaner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) for this purpose, which allows not to register a cleaner when a `FileInputStream` or `FileOutputStream` is constructed using an existing `FileDescriptor`, which is the case for stdin and stdout. It also allows immediate cleaning and hence deregistration in the `close()` method, not needing any post-mortem cleanup for well behaved programs.

So with the newest Java versions, you should see only cleaners for streams actually in use in the heap dump.